# Can I create a few different changes to an element content using one XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I got an XML document that looks like:

```
<Patient>
    <Treatment>
        <Medications>
            <Medication>
                <MedicationCode>X</MedicationCode>
            </Medication>
        </Medications>
        <Procedures>
            <Procedure>
                <ProcdName>A</ProcdName>
            </Procedure>
            <Procedure>
                <ProcdName>B</ProcdName>
            </Procedure>
        </Procedures>
    </Treatment>
</Patient>
```

and after transformation it should look like this:

```
<Patient>
    <Procedures>
        <ProcdName>A</ProcdName>
    </Procedures>
    <Procedures>
        <ProcdName>B</ProcdName>
    </Procedures>
</Patient>
```

I managed to do it, but only by using 4 different XSL transformations: first one to remove the Medications element all together, second one to remove the Treatment element but keep its content, third to remove the Procedures element, and fourth to rename the Procedure elements to Procedures. When I tried to do it all in one transformation, only some of them took effect. Is it because they all modifying related elements? Is there a way to make it all with one transformation?

UPDATE - 25/05/2017

Sorry about that, but here is really the full picture.
Original XML:

```
<ns0:PatMedData xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
<MessageId>AS80000000000041</MessageId>
<Status>3</Status>
<UpdateNumber>001</UpdateNumber>
<UpdateReason/>
<TargetCode>2</TargetCode>
<ServiceProviderType>1</ServiceProviderType>
<ServiceProviderCode>1761</ServiceProviderCode>
<UnitType>2</UnitType>
<UnitCode>33845</UnitCode>
<ExecuteTime>2017-01-22T14:20:00</ExecuteTime>
<ExecuteDocID>3575718</ExecuteDocID>
<ExecuteDocName>Dr</ExecuteDocName>
<ExecuteDocLic>654788</ExecuteDocLic>
<DiagnosticTime>2017-05-10T15:09:21</DiagnosticTime>
<DiagnosticanDocID/>
<DiagnosticanDocName/>
<DiagnosticanDocLic/>
<MessageSubType>26</MessageSubType>
<RelatedDocID/>
<RelatedDocName/>
<PatID>2232</PatID>
<IDPatCode>1</IDPatCode>
<PatLastName>last</PatLastName>
<PatFirstName>first</PatFirstName>
<ExaminationName></ExaminationName>
<PDFFiles>
    <FileName>as80000000000041011.pdf</FileName>
    <FileContent/>
</PDFFiles>
<Solved/>
<Pathological>3</Pathological>
<AccNum/>
<HitNum/>
<Parameters>
    <Parameter>
        <ParameterCode>31</ParameterCode>
        <HebText/>
        <EngText/>
        <Numerical>0</Numerical>
    </Parameter>
</Parameters>
<Absences>
    <Absence>
        <AbsenceStratDate/>
        <AbsenceDep/>
        <AbsenceType/>
        <AbsenceEndDate/>
    </Absence>
</Absences>
<Prognosis>
    <Sensitivities>
        <Sensitivity>
            <SensitivityDate>2017-04-23 09:42:05</SensitivityDate>
            <SensitivityCode/>
            <SensitivityType>Other</SensitivityType>
            <SensitivityName>Latex</SensitivityName>
            <SensitivityCreated>2017-04-23 09:42:05</SensitivityCreated>
        </Sensitivity>
    </Sensitivities>
    <Diags>
        <Diag>
            <DiagName>Blighted ovum</DiagName>
            <DiagCode>631.8</DiagCode>
            <DiagMod/>
            <DiagDetail/>
            <DiagDate>2017-02-20 00:00:00</DiagDate>
            <DiagStatus/>
            <DiagSide/>
            <DiagCertainty/>
            <DiagSPerformer>Dr</DiagSPerformer>
            <DiagCreated>2017-02-20 17:22:11</DiagCreated>
            <DiagPriority/>
            <DiagSolved/>
        </Diag>
    </Diags>
</Prognosis>
<Treatment>
    <Medications>
        <Medication>
            <MedicationCode>136688</MedicationCode>
            <MedicationStatus>Recommendation</MedicationStatus>
            <MedicationCaption>SIFROL tab 0.25mg</MedicationCaption>
            <MedicationForm>tab</MedicationForm>
            <MedicationIngredient>PRAMIPEXOLE</MedicationIngredient>
            <MedicationDosage>0.25 mg</MedicationDosage>
            <MedicationRate>2</MedicationRate>
            <MedicationRoute>P.O</MedicationRoute>
            <MedicationInstruction/>
            <MedicationCreated>2017-04-23 09:45:58</MedicationCreated>
            <MedicationDuration>20</MedicationDuration>
        </Medication>
    </Medications>
    <Procedures>
        <Procedure>
            <ProcdName>Blighted ovum</ProcdName>
            <ProcdCode>631.8</ProcdCode>
            <ProcdDetail/>
            <ProcdValidity>2017-02-20 17:08:36</ProcdValidity>
            <ProcdClass>SRG</ProcdClass>
            <ProcdStatus>Actual</ProcdStatus>
            <ProcdPerformer>Dr</ProcdPerformer>
            <ProcdSide/>
            <ProcdCreated>2017-02-20 17:08:36</ProcdCreated>
        </Procedure>
        <Procedure>
            <ProcdName>Blighted ovum</ProcdName>
            <ProcdCode>631.8</ProcdCode>
            <ProcdDetail/>
            <ProcdValidity>2017-02-20 17:12:19</ProcdValidity>
            <ProcdClass>SRG</ProcdClass>
            <ProcdStatus>Actual</ProcdStatus>
            <ProcdPerformer>Dr</ProcdPerformer>
            <ProcdSide/>
            <ProcdCreated>2017-02-20 17:12:19</ProcdCreated>
        </Procedure>
    </Procedures>
</Treatment>
<SeverityCode/>
<internet>1</internet>
<VisitCode>90800314</VisitCode>
<CompletePatID>000002232</CompletePatID>
<ExamCode/>
</ns0:PatMedData>
```

After XSLT:

```
<ns0:PatMedData xmlns:ns0="http://Maccabi.Hospitals.Integration">
<MessageId>AS80000000000041</MessageId>
<Status>3</Status>
<UpdateNumber>001</UpdateNumber>
<UpdateReason/>
<TargetCode>2</TargetCode>
<ServiceProviderType>1</ServiceProviderType>
<ServiceProviderCode>1761</ServiceProviderCode>
<UnitType>2</UnitType>
<UnitCode>33845</UnitCode>
<ExecuteTime>2017-01-22T14:20:00</ExecuteTime>
<ExecuteDocID>3575718</ExecuteDocID>
<ExecuteDocName>Dr</ExecuteDocName>
<ExecuteDocLic>654788</ExecuteDocLic>
<DiagnosticTime>2017-05-10T15:09:21</DiagnosticTime>
<DiagnosticanDocID/>
<DiagnosticanDocName/>
<DiagnosticanDocLic/>
<MessageSubType>26</MessageSubType>
<RelatedDocID/>
<RelatedDocName/>
<PatID>2232</PatID>
<IDPatCode>1</IDPatCode>
<PatLastName>last</PatLastName>
<PatFirstName>first</PatFirstName>
<ExaminationName></ExaminationName>
<PDFFiles>
    <FileName>as80000000000041011.pdf</FileName>
    <FileContent/>
</PDFFiles>
<Solved/>
<Pathological>3</Pathological>
<AccNum/>
<HitNum/>
<Prognosis>
    <Diags>
        <Diag>
            <DiagName>Blighted ovum</DiagName>
            <DiagCode>631.8</DiagCode>
            <DiagMod/>
            <DiagDetail/>
        </Diag>
    </Diags>
</Prognosis>
<Procedures>
    <ProcdName>Blighted ovum</ProcdName>
    <ProcdCode>631.8</ProcdCode>
    <ProcdDetail/>
</Procedures>
<Procedures>
    <ProcdName>Blighted ovum</ProcdName>
    <ProcdCode>631.8</ProcdCode>
    <ProcdDetail/>
</Procedures>
<SeverityCode/>
<internet>1</internet>
<VisitCode>90800314</VisitCode>
<CompletePatID>000002232</CompletePatID>
<ExamCode/>
</ns0:PatMedData>
```

In order to make it clearer, these are the XSLs that I am using, and as I said they do give me the correct output, but only when run as 4 separate transformations.
XSL1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="Absences"/>
    <xsl:template match="Sensitivities"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagDate"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagStatus"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagSide"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagCertainty"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagSPerformer"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagCreated"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagPriority"/>
    <xsl:template match="DiagSolved"/>      
    <xsl:template match="Medications"/>         
    <xsl:template match="ProcdValidity"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcdClass"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcdStatus"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcdPerformer"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcdSide"/>
    <xsl:template match="ProcdCreated"/>                
    <xsl:template match="Parameters[Parameter/ParameterCode='31']"/>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match ="Treatment">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>                 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match ="Procedures">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL4:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="Procedure">
    <Procedures><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></Procedures>
    </xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry for the long story, but I am quite new to XSL, and it looks like I cannot explain my issue any shorter. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with one transform.  If you present your stylesheet that attempts this, then we can help you fix it.

Comment: Your input and output XMLs don't match (the `<FileContent>` and `<Sensitivities>` elements, for example), but I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is there no middle ground between a small example that does not represent your real input and dumping the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

This simple stylesheet should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--
    Whenever you see one of these elements, only apply the rules for all
    child elements of that element, but don't copy the element itself
    into the output.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="Treatment | Procedures">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    Use an empty template to omit an element from the output completely.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="Medications | Parameters | Absences | Sensitivities"/>

    <!--
    For every <Procedure> element, create a <Procedures> element.

    Apply the templates for the selected child elements. In this case, the
    template that matches each of <ProcdName>, <ProcdCode> and <ProcdDetail>
    is the identity template (see below), so those nodes are copied into the
    output XML as is.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="Procedure">
        <Procedures>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ProcdName | ProcdCode | ProcdDetail"/>
        </Procedures>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    XSLT identity transform. The XSLT processor applies this template for
    every node in the source document that doesn't match a more specific
    template (that is, a template with a higher priority).

    See:

    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform
    http://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/#conflict_resolution_for_template_rules
    -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Eero, I have updated my question with all the relevant info, please will you have another look?